# Как вывести Строку Данных с Mysql используя Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

Мой Контроллер:

```
$referslist = DB::table('users')->where('referals', '1')
->whereNotNull('contract');

return view('client-area.index',['referlist' => $referslist]);
```

Моя Страница Показа:

```
    @foreach($referlist as $refers)
      <div class="infsSfp09kO">
      <span>{{ $refers }}</span>
      </div>
    @endforeach
```

Мне нужно вывести все строки где `contracts` не NULL

Comment: ну а выводится то что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ваш код.

```
DB::table('users')->where('referals', '1')->whereNotNull('contract');
```

Он возвращает `QueryBuilder`.

Добавте `get()` и вернутся результаты запроса.

```
DB::table('users')->where('referals', '1')->whereNotNull('contract')->get();
```

А еще лучше это сделать через модель `User`.

```
User::query()->where('referals', '1')->whereNotNull('contract')->get();
```

Или добавь `scopeActiveReferals()` в модель юзера.

```
User::query()->scopeActiveReferals()->whereNotNull('contract')->get();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое